# How to restrict or deny the access to particular folder or file?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, restriction, server.xml

When I put this line in Tomcat Server `.xml` file under host:

```
<Context docBase="c:\Documents and Settings\The User\videos" path="/videos />
```

I can access the images without a problem when I run the project like
`localhost:8080/example/videos/smile.WebM`, for exmple. 
The problem is when I run the server without project and still am able to access the images with the url `localhost:8080/videos/smile.WebM`.
The image is still available. How to restrict or deny the access to this if I directly put the url without project name it shouldn't give access to that particular folder or image it is in .

Comment: Is this a static set of videos?  Or do u want to be able to modify the set using the application?  Add new ones.  Removes old ones?

Comment: it's a static set of videos, may add new ones but dont have to remove old ones.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access the images in absence of project also because `server.xml` belongs to full tomcat but not to particular project.

My recommendation would be not to use this approach, instead store images inside project folder so that will be accessible within projects only.

Comment: then how to dynamically get videos on request and it shouldnt be shared with the others like when we open the developers tab and u can see your video over there on response page and when you tried to do with right click and open in a new tab on that particular video then it shouldnt open in a new tab .how to restrict that ? @Sandeep Rathore

Comment: you can not control new tab in browser instead what you can do is to secure your URL which is loading the video.(have a look at preauthorize annotation and spring role based security)..thank you

Comment: suggest me a way to put put videos in such a way that the source cant be hidden or block accessing the videos if the the url doesnt have a project name.